# Unable to show icon in Tab Bar iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Despite trying various methods posted on SO, I was unable to have the simulator display tab bar icons when initialising the tab bar controller.

For each icon, I provided 3 sizes i.e. 25px by 25px, 50px by 50px (@2x) and 75px by 75px (@3x).

This is how my Tabbar is showing up in the simulator
[image]

Below are the Tab and Image attributes respectively

[image]
[image]

Here is one of my icon at 75px x 75px (@3x)

[image]

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you running the Beta? All my icons stopped showing in Beta, but do show on my phone.

Comment: Check for insets of image you adding and try Importing a small image like 50Px for trying and Xcode Version are you using And try launching application on device too maybe its just Simulator problem

Comment: @Diesel That right I am running in X code 9 Beta, I tried launching on my device but the images still don't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that the problem was to do with the `xcassets` folder. To solve this I created a new `xcassets` folder in Xcode.

1. `File > New > Resource > Asset Catalog`.
2. As shown below I made sure my target application is selected as well.

I dragged and dropped the images from the old `xcassets` folder to the new one and all the images were loading.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 3.0**

**Set programmatically for selected Tab and un-selected Tab Images**

```
    let arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState = ["tabBar_img_1", "tabBar_img_2", "tabBar_img_3"]
    let arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState = ["tabBar_img_1", "tabBar_img_2", "tabBar_img_3"]

    if let count = self.tabBar.items?.count {

        for i in 0...(count-1) {

            let imageNameForSelectedState   = arrayOfImageNameForSelectedState[i]
            let imageNameForUnselectedState = arrayOfImageNameForUnselectedState[i]

            self.tabBar.items?[i].selectedImage = UIImage(named: imageNameForSelectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            self.tabBar.items?[i].image = UIImage(named: imageNameForUnselectedState)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modify like this:-

[image]

> And then update your custom image programmatically

```
if let tabBarItems = yourTabBar?.items {
  tabBarItems[0].selectedImage(UIImage(name: yourImage)
}
```